# Orchard use ICacheManager to cache authenticated user data

Tags: caching, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I am using Orchard and would like to cache data specific to an authenticated user.

When a new user logs in, or after a period of time, the database should be queried again.

I've accomplished half of this below (after 30 minutes it will query the database again):

```
private UserData SomeUserSpecificData()
{
    var data = _cacheManager.Get("userdata",
        ctx => {
            ctx.Monitor(_clock.When(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
            return GetDatabaseData();
        });

    return data;
}
```

But how would I force the cache to re-query the database when a new user has logged in?

I have a feeling it might involve ISignals but not sure how to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: did my answer help you or do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right with `ISignals`!

You just need to inject `ISignals` and use it like this:

```cs
private readonly Orchard.Caching.ISignals _signals;

private UserData SomeUserSpecificData()
{
  var data = _cacheManager.Get("userdata",
      ctx => {
        ctx.Monitor(_clock.When(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
        cts.Monitor(_signals.When("SOMETHING_HAPPENED_FOR_xyz"));

        return GetDatabaseData();
      });
  return data;
}
```

What's also nice to know: [You can monitor as many signals as you want.](https://gitter.im/OrchardCMS/Orchard/archives/2017/03/28)

To keep things clean I'll typically create a static class like this:

```cs
public static class CacheSignals
{
  public const string SomethingHappened = "SOMETHING_HAPPENED";
  public const string SomethingHappenedForUser(int userId) => string.Format("SOMETHING_HAPPENED_FOR_{0}", userId);
}
```

Now you can simply implement a custom EventHandler for`Orchard.Users.Events.IUserEventHandler`
and invalidate the cache on [`LoggedIn`](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/blob/6720b71cf3474a9a7b8a8cc9a99d58b1e733acfa/src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Users/Events/IUserEventHandler.cs#L24).

```cs
private readonly Orchard.Caching.ISignals _signals;

public void LoggedIn(Security.IUser user)
{
    _signals.Trigger(CacheSignals.SomethingHappenedForUser(user.Id));
}
```